# Parameterize a class with a known Type

Tags: scala

Why are the two method definitions below not compiling?

`b.head` should compile because `b` is a "custom type" of List.

`List[T](a)` is of type `List[T]` which is the same as `genericList`

```
type T = Any

type genericList = List[T] 

class usesGenericList[genericList](val a: T, b: genericList){

  def head() = b.head 
  // error: value head is not a member of type parameter genericList

  def returnGenericList: genericList = List[T](a) 
 // error: found: List[$sess.cmd203.T](which expands to)  List[Any] required: genericList

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shadow outer `type genericList` with `class usesGenericList[genericList]`. Just remove class type parameter.